# Second display abruptly not working at full resolution (was fine yesterday)

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors

I have an HP laptop running 16.04 I use for work. I have it attached to a dock with a display port which goes to my external monitor.

I've been working remotely for 2 weeks without any issues. Today when I plugged it in, my monitor claims "No Signal" (Ubuntu believes it's attached to it though). After some fiddling, I've found I can now run it at anything except the monitor's native resolution. It's natively 3440x1440. When I set it to that it goes off and my laptop believes it's connected to a display but nothing comes on screen. If I drop it to 2560x1080 or lower it works fine. There is an `xrandr` entry for `DP-2` with the correct resolution and refresh rate.

I haven't updated my system since Friday, and it was working fine then. I do not believe it's the monitor as my personal desktop can run it at the native resolution just fine with the same display port & cable. I've tried all obvious things like restarting, plugging in cables in various orders, checking the input, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer. `xrandr` had for some reason dropped a mode. It was trying to refresh at 75Hz which the integrated GPU probably couldn't handle. Creating a new mode and forcing it to 60Hz worked.

I'd never noticed but it's probably always been using this monitor at 60Hz even though it supports 75.